# Searching for exact string within a string with String.includes()

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to search for exact string/word within a string/sentence with includes() and I want it to return true if it does. But I get returned "true" even if word matches part of a bigger word. How do I approach searching for *exact* match? I realize that includes() is case sensetive but I want it to be length sensitive so to say, I understand I should probably somehow define what a word in a string for js is but not sure how to do it with includes(). Thanks

```js
var sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
var word = 'own';
console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.includes(word)? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
```

```
// wanted output: "The word "own" is not in the sentence"
// real output: "The word "own" is in the sentence"
```

Comment: You can't do it with String#includes, because that's not what String#includes does. Use something else like `(new RegExp( \`\\b${RegExp.escape(word)}\\b\` )).test( sentence )`, where RegExp.escape is the function defined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript

Comment: Actually you should just split on non-word characters and check if the array includes your word `sentence.split( /\W+/g ).includes( word )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includes` tries to search any sequence which matches the passed string ( parameter ), in this case `brown` has `own` in it so it returns true, where as you want it to match only when exact word `own` is found you can use `search` and `regex`,

```js
var sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

let wordFounder = word => {
  let reg = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`)
  console.log(`The word "${word}" is ${sentence.search(reg) !== -1 ? '' : 'not'} 
in the sentence`);  
}

wordFounder("own")
wordFounder("brown")
```

Comment: weird but this code return false for words that should return true and I cannot fix it at a glance, basically it just always returns false for me. gonna go read up on regExp

Comment: @SanchezPanza what do you mean by that ? can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Using your code if the word is "brown" for example it should say that it's in the sentance, but it always says it's not. (for example, if I use sentence.search(reg) , it should return true if the word is in the sentence and false if its not right?)

Comment: @SanchezPanza i missed escapping , look at the updated one, i have made an generic function with some example words

Comment: Thanks mr.Maniac! so the trouble was with the \\b and whats the difference between this and \b ? Also I didnt know that you dont have to put vars in brackets when defining a function in es6 style

Comment: Just note that this will also match things like: `" "`, `"."`, `""` and `"quick brown"`.

Comment: It will also match things like `\\s`, `.*`, `|`, and `monkey|` because there is no escaping for regex being used. It is also vulnerable to DOS attacks if it is server side and `word` comes from user input. Change `${word}` to use a properly escaped `word` instead (use the answer I linked in a comment on the question to see how to escape `word`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
const result = sentence.search(word) != -1;
```

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: @Rob to get true or false

Comment: How does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You could break it into words and then use `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
var sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
var word = 'own';
console.log(`The word "${word}" ${sentence.match(/\b\S+\b/g).includes(word)? 'is' : 'is not'} in the sentence`);
```

`sentence.match(/\b\S+\b/g)` basically breaks your sentence in an array like:

```
["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
```

And then `includes` just searches for the word there.

Comment: That works, buts becomes heavy if there is an array of strings imho?

Answer (score 0):

If the word is not coming in the start or end of the sentence you can just add space

var word = ' own ';

then you can get an exact match with same include function